# How to add custom css to login and admin?

Tags: admin-css

I have custom CSS for the login and admin pages.

Is it OK to add it as I've done below, or is there a better alternative?

```
function custom_admin_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/admin.css', array(), filemtime( get_template_directory() . '/css/admin.css' ) );
}
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_admin_css', 10 );
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_admin_css', 10 );
```

Comment: @the_dramatist Thanks for the edit. Rushed, I hadn't noticed my error.

Comment: Oh. You welcome. We are a community. Feel free to edit any other post or suggest edit if you see any error.

Comment: Dear @glvr, I added a file with my custom CSS to themes/themename/css/admin.css and added the code to the functions.php but the changes are not showing. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's pretty fine and it's the proper way to add CSS to login page. But you can also change login page CSS by below code-

```
function the_dramatist_custom_login_css() {
    echo '<style type="text/css"> //Write your css here </style>';
}
add_action('login_head', 'the_dramatist_custom_login_css');
```

This actually prints CSS code inline in the login page. And for admin CSS your way is correct.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know if it's ok to combine the 2 'add_action' into one function.

Comment: No it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to add CSS to the content created with help of jQuery so the above methods will not work if jquery code loads in the footer. you can use the below code too.

```php
    function the_king_custom_login_css() {
        echo '<style type="text/css">
        .nsl-container {
            text-align:center !important;
        }
        </style>';
    }
    add_action('wp_footer', 'the_king_custom_login_css');
```

Comment: Awesome tip. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

as explained at [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_head/)  you can do as below:

```
// custom login for theme
function childtheme_custom_login() {
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . 
   get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/customlogin.css" />';
}

add_action('login_head', 'childtheme_custom_login');
```

**another way for plugin:**

If you want to load extra css for login page from your plugin you can do as below:

I assume you know basics of wp plugin development.

make a css directory in your plugin directory create a login.css file.

in your init function add this.

```
  public static function init(){
       //other function as your need
      add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', __CLASS__.'::custom_login_css', 10 );
   }
```

then you can write function like this.

```
public static function custom_login_css(){
        wp_enqueue_style('custom_login_css', plugins_url('/css/login.css', __FILE__), [], '1.0.0');
    }
```